# Construction of factor groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was reading Fraleigh's *Abstract Algebra* about the construction factor groups from normal subgroups and he defines it as following:

**Theorem:** Let $ H $ be a subgroup of a group $ G $. If the left coset multiplication is well-defined by the equation
$$ \displaystyle (aH)(bH) = (ab)H $$
then $ H $ is normal.

**Proof:** Let $ x \in aH. $ Choosing representatives $ x \in aH $ and $ a^{-1} \in a^{-1}H, $ we have $ (xH)(a^{-1}H) = (xa^{-1})H. $ On the other hand, choosing representatives $ a \in aH $ and $ a^{-1} \in a^{-1}H, $ we have $ (aH)(a^{-1}H) = (aa^{-1})H = eH = H. $ **Using our assumption that the left coset multiplication by representatives is well-defined, we must have $ xa^{-1} = h \in H. $** Then $ x = ha \in Ha $ and so $ aH \subseteq Ha. $ Similarly $ Ha \subseteq aH. $ Therefore $ aH = Ha, $ so $ H $ is normal.

I don't understand the bold sentence in the proof. I understand that the left coset multiplication is well-defined means that it doesn't matter what representatives you choose, but I don't understand why it must imply that $ xa^{-1} = h \in H. $

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because $xa^{-1}H=H$, hence every element in the l.h.s. – in particular $xa^{-1}$ – belongs to $H$.

Comment: How do you know that $ xa^{-1}H = H? $ Is it because the coset multiplication is well-defined?

Comment: @PhucNguyen: Yes. That is, more or less, the content of that statement.

Comment: It's in the assumptions for the proof: the product is calculated with two different sets of representatives, and  the result must be the same.